# Ruby 'require' vs Java 'import'

Tags: java, ruby, import, require

In ["ruby's official site"](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/to-ruby-from-java/) it is stated that in the "differences" section that "You have require instead of import." I believe this statement says that they perform the same function.

In java if I want to use the `Random` class, I can either import it and use it like

```
import java.util.Random;

public class JavaTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();       
        System.out.println("The random number is - " + random.nextInt(50));
    }
}
```

or I can use the fully qualified name **without using import** like

```
public class JavaTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random();       
        System.out.println("The random number is - " + random.nextInt(50));
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use ruby's require in this way?

- If yes, how to?
- If not, aren't java's `import` and ruby's `require` different from each other?

Answer (score 1):

**They're the same:**

You use `require` if you need something it contains<sup>1</sup>. The same in Java; if the symbol is outside the current package you must either `import` it or use its FQN.

**They're different:**

In Java an `import` is syntactic convenience–an import doesn't "load the file" when the statement is encountered. In Ruby the file is read and executed.

<sup>1  Dissimilarly, *something* must load the required file in Ruby, you can't just use an FQN before the file containing the artifact has been loaded. There are multiple ways to get access to required libraries, like something else in the system doing the `require`, like auto-loading libs in Rails.</sup>

Comment: You need to use require to use something that a *file* contains. If you need something that a module contains, you'll need to `include` the module or use the fully qualified name. In Java you don't need to do anything to access other files (except possibly set the class path correctly). If a class is not inside a different package, you can just use it. So they're not the same in any sense.

Comment: @sepp2k I don't have any problem with the surface-level view that one has `require` and one has `import`, but it's just that: a surface-level view, which is what the link is.

Comment: By that surface level view would `include` and `require` be the same thing? Because those seem fundamentally different to me.

Comment: @sepp2k I wouldn't think they'd be the same thing at the surface level. Please direct your concerns to ruby-lang. I find it impossible to get worked up about the actual mechanics of this glossy bullet point.